# Can you pass URL parameters to a sidebar gadget when adding it to google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-gadget, apache-shindig

Where the typical URL to add an html content type gadget would be
http://www.google.com/calendar/render?gadgeturl=http://www.example.com/hello.xml&nocache=1

can query parameters be appended to this (for tracking entry vectors) that won't be stripped by the container? Or can you arbitrarily set the module ID (query param "mid") to use it for this purpose? I've unsuccessfully tried appending "mid=[value]" and, in the gadget's javascript,

```
var moduleId = new gadgets.Prefs().getModuleId();
```

This returns the default value (0) regardless of value passed for mid. mid and all custom variables are stripped, as can be seen inside the gadget iframe in the "url" parameter value of window.location.href.

Comment: You may want to visit this [Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/) wherein you will find guidelines in [developing](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#developing) and [publicizing](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#publicizing) your gadget and  [gadget features that Google Calendar supports](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#features). There's also information about certain functions that cannot be used if you're using `type="html"` gadgets.

Comment: "nocache" is documented, as is "mid", but no other information that would be of use for this problem.